# Is there a halal sex guide for Muslims?

Tags: nikah, practical-islam, sex

Are there any books in English which describe in detail sexual techniques and positions without compromising the religion in terms of nudity etc.?

Muslim doctors are allowed to look at all parts of the body when students and in the job, so why can't we look at such in a book perhaps in a diagram anatomically as photos would be a bit too far.

Sexual Positions. How are you supposed to know these (the [Qur'an 2:223](http://quran.com/2:223) says you can go to your wife in any position). Perhaps the book could have matchstick or cartoon type drawings of man and woman without being explicit.

I would be surprised if no such book exists.

Comment: Salam and welcome to Islam SE the Q&A site about Islam. Please consider to take some time to learn mroe about this site and our model by taking our [tour] and checking our [help].

Comment: First photographs and drawings are considered as haram by the majority of scholars. There are books by Muslim scholars on this issue describing what you ask about with enough details.

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a halal sex guide for Muslims?

Yes. Muslim American Community Association lists a book named [Islamic Guide To 
Sexual Relations](http://www.macanj.org/books-2/) written by Mufti Mubammad ibn Adam al-Kawthari.

The book claims to discuss sexual relations exhaustively in light of the teachings of the Qur'an, Sunna, reference works from 
the four Sunni Schools of Islamic law, and other works of classical and 
contemporary scholars.

A page of that book: [image]

Comment: Downvoters, may I know what's wrong with this post? Your feedback will help me improve it.

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting guide I saw a few months ago. Let me copy paste part of it here since the entire guide is humongous!

2 How to spice up your sex life the Halal way!

2.1 Is Sex really that important?

2.2 Express your Love, Women!

2.3 Shyness in Bedroom!

2.4 How to please your wife/husband

2.5 Kindness – Be Kind To Each Other!

2.6 Romance – Do something romantic for your partner every once in while!

2.7 Remembrance of Allah – Remember Allah All The Time!

2.8 Compromises – Mismatched Sex Drives

2.9 Modern Economy – Make Time For Each Other

2.10 Men Are From Mars, Women Are From Venus

Source: The Halal Sex Guide https://www.hidden-pearls.co.uk/the-hijab-diaries/the-halal-sex-guide-bonus-wedding-night-guide-for-muslims/

Answer (score -1):

Yes:  Enjoy Amazing Halal Sex!: Great Sex Keeps The Heart Of Marriage Alive, Layla Rashid, 2014:

> Enjoy Amazing Halal Sex shows you how AMAZING sex can be. Explore and discover the pleasures of the flesh, Halal-style. ([amazon.com](https://www.amazon.co.uk/Enjoy-Amazing-Halal-Sex-Marriage/dp/1502594021))
>
> The first sex guide that shows you how to enjoy sex in a halal manner. It contains over tons of different ways for you the husband and wife to have and enjoy amazing sex that'll keep your marriage healthy, happy and sexually satisfying. ([createspace](https://www.createspace.com/5030830))

This goes into details about the mechanics and biology and keeping halal.

Answer (score -1):

There are 2 books written by Irfan Ullah Khan that deal with the matters related to sexual life in the light of Quran and Sunnah. Here are the 2 books:

1. The Halal Sex Guide: 
   https://happymuslimfamily.org/halal-sex-guide/
2. Better Love with Better Half:
   https://happymuslimfamily.org/better-love-with-better-half/

The book "The Halal Sex Guide" discusses how to spice up the sex life from the practical point of view, whereas "Better Love with Better Half" deals mostly with sharai matters and fiqh opinions though it also has some chapters on tips and techniques.

Hope that answers the question.

Answer (score -4):

you can check the book [Couples Sex Guide with Demonstrated Sex Positions](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00FUQQF26)
it is not specifically halal but it has detailed explanations and more than 100 demonstrated sex positions by couples in shorts, therefore no nudity. personally for us we were a mature couple and were recommended by a friend, and it is true, you get the appropriate knowledge without the nudity. good luck

Comment: In islam, every muslim is Obliged Only to stick to Halal and Never haram , in any case.

Answer (score -6):

There are now many sexual guides for Muslims. We cannot enumerate all of them. We are authors of a self-help ebook on the subject, you can find it on [Amazon](https://www.amazon.com/s?k=the%20perfumed%20garden%202&i=stripbooks&crid=1YVIABIHP1K4X&sprefix=the%20perfumed%20garden%202%2Cstripbooks%2C163&ref=nb_sb_noss) as well as [other sources](https://theperfumedgarden2.wordpress.com). There is a lot of good content out there but it is all text-based. Given that we live and learn visually, we invested in a couple of hundred illustrations to complement the text. The title is ["The Perfumed Garden 2 : A Sensual Spiritual Sex Manual" by Ali Dada and Laila Din.](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0BFQXS3V1)
Check it out. We also have a blog with related posts at [theperfumedgarden2.wordpress.com](https://theperfumedgarden2.wordpress.com)

Comment: Salam and welcome to IslamSE the Q&A site about Islam. To learn more about our site and model consider taking the [tour] and checking our [help]. I would also like to ask that in the future, please concentrate on answering the question asked and avoid misusing the site for self-promotion.